# Is it necessary to encrypt all the data in node.js

Tags: node.js, database, authentication, mongoose, encryption

I am currently learning Node.js authentication. There's something I don't understand and I would be grateful if you could help me. Well I know how to protect password with "passport", "session"... Currently I am making ToDo list website. If hacker somehow got access to my database, he would see all the data users have written without knowing password, right?

So is it necessary to encrypt the whole data?

Comment: Well, it's first necessary to secure access to the database.  Nobody from the outside world should have network access and even when your server gets access, it should require credentials.  If you were going to encrypt the data in the database, then you'd have to secure the encryption key so that doesn't get you out of having to secure things.  If a hacker has access to your database, you have much bigger problems as they apparently have access to many other things too.

Comment: Can you tell me how hackers are hacking websites?

Comment: There are thousands of ways that hackers can cause trouble and there are multiple layers of security that are required to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no security expert but you can think security as layers. Encrypting the whole database is another layer of security. If a hacker would get physical access to the server and the hard drive was not encrypted, yeah he/she probably could read the data. But I would still think that it's more important to have the "accessing" layer secure (login process etc.)

You need to decrypt the data for your users anyway and if the login process is not securely programmed, the hacker could access the data that way.